# External data for pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I need to use XML file (preferably not local, but pointed by URL) as data source for Excel 2007 pivot table.

But "Use external data source" radio button is disabled on the "Change pivot data source" dialog. What should I do to enable it? Change some security settings or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you can use an external data source is dependant, among other things, on the activecell when you select the pivot wizard.  Try a blank, unlocked cell that is not in a table/list.

Comment: I learned what I can select external data source when creating new pivot table, but I once I choosed cell range I can change it to external source no more.